# Callback function in gurobipy yields error messages

Tags: python, attributeerror, gurobi

While working on my project, I need to change my MIP-model with a callback function. I followed the documentation closely, but I get always an error message.
I believe, the error comes with the cbGet-function, without this, I get an output, although I don't know whether it's correct.

Without the callback function, my model works just fine.

Here's my code:

```
import gurobipy as gb
...
some code with the model
...
def cb(mod, where):
    if where == gb.GRB.Callback.MIP:
        print(mod.cbGet(gb.GRB.Callback.MIP_NODCNT))
def cb2(mod, where):
    if where == gb.GRB.Callback.MIP:
        print(gb.GRB.Callback.MIP_NODCNT)
m.optimize(cb(m, gb.GRB.Callback.MIP))
```

Please note that if I use `cb2` as callback function, I get the exit code 0 and an output. I'm not sure whether this output is right.
But when I'm using `cb` as callback function, I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/dbigb/PycharmProjects/MA/MIP_model.py", line 39, in <module> m.optimize(cb(m, gb.GRB.Callback.MIP))
    File "C:/Users/dbigb/PycharmProjects/MA/MIP_model.py", line 32, in cb print(mod.cbGet(gb.GRB.Callback.MIP_NODCNT))
    File "model.pxi", line 4136, in gurobipy.Model.cbGet
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_cbdata'
```

I don't understand which attribute is none, neither what this `_cbdata` is or where I could find and check this. Any help would be appreciated.

I didn't include the whole model, since it's working fine. If it's important for the solution I will edit the question and add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `optimize` as follows:

```
m.optimize(cb)
```

The [`optimize`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_optimize.html) method expects an argument of type function.

In your code, `cb(m, gb.GRB.Callback.MIP)` would be evaluated (and become a constant) before starting the optimization.

In the `cb2` case, this simply prints `3002`, i.e., the integer representation of `gb.GRB.Callback.MIP_NODCNT`. ([See here.](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/java_constants.html)) The argument of `optimize` evaluates to `None`.

In the `cb` case, the call to `cbGet` tries to access the model's callback, which is not defined. This is the `NoneType` in the error message.